# How to remove HTC Sync calendar entries?

Tags: htc-desire, calendar, htc-sync-3.0

I made the mistake of sync'ing my PC with my HTC Desire and now my calendar has lots of double entries; From Exchange and from HTC Sync (Outlook)... Any wy to remove all traces of the HTC Sync entries?

Comment: Usually everything that's synced uses a corresponding content-provider. Did you check in *settings -> accounts & sync* whether there's a corresponding account/entry? If so, you could try to remove it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I've had a bunch of phones since my Desire... I'm using a Nokia Lumia 800 (loving it) now, so no idea if your comment is valid or not. :)

Comment: Oh -- OK, so we have to wait for another user with the same problem to turn up and leave a comment... Thanks for clarification anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the steps I took on my HTC Desire running Android version 2.2 to delete all calendar data, and in turn the PC Sync calendar:

1. On the phone, open Settings > Applications > Manage Applications
2. Click the “All” tab at the top of the screen
3. Scroll down and tap the Calendar Storage application
4. Tap the “Clear data” button, and confirm you’d like to proceed.

Now all the calendar data is gone from the phone, running your sync processes again to populate only the calendars you want on your phone.

Comment: This may be correct, I have switched phone three times since and wouldn't have a clue if this works. Will mark it as the answer though, looks like the author has done this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but if you go to Calenendars -> Menu -> More -> Calendars, you can choose which calendar to show. Maybe this will help if you are talking about calendar of phone.

Comment: This will hide them, true, but not remove them...

Answer (score -1):

On HTC, go to Settings - App, search for "Calendar Storage", open it, then "Clear data". Done.